# duplicate file error while pushing --mirror into Git repository

Tags: linux, git, github

I need to push my existing repository to another empty repository in Git. I was getting this following error:

```
remote: unpack error Invalid tree 300894f515: duplicate entry names
error: unpack failed: error Invalid tree 300894f515: duplicate entry names
```

After trying several options I was able to rewrite the history and push the master branch finally. But when I am trying to push the `--mirror` again, it is showing the same error. I am attaching the log here.

1. `git clone URL`
2. `git branch -a`

   ```
   * master
   remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
   remotes/origin/MyTestBranch
   remotes/origin/ABC
   remotes/origin/XYZ
   remotes/origin/TEST
   ```
3. `git remote add test REMOTE URL`
4. `git remote -v`

   ```
   origin  git@github.................. (fetch)
   origin  git@github................... (push)
   test    https://abc........................................... (fetch)
   test    https://abc........................................... (push)
   ```
5. `git fsck --full`

   ```
   error in tree 300894f515b714a42efd603f4196d45c8c1f3c09: contains duplicate file entries
   error in tree a84c6e1cc242cdc4c7d7ce5246be02672d1eaf3a: contains duplicate file entries
   ```
6. `git filter-branch --index-filter 'mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.tmp" && GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.tmp git ls-files -s | git update-index --index-info'`
7. `git push test master`

   ```
   Counting objects: 33396, done.
   Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
   Compressing objects: 100% (10456/10456), done.
   Writing objects: 100% (33396/33396), 86.61 MiB | 16.05 MiB/s, done.
   Total 33396 (delta 17522), reused 31573 (delta 17001)
   remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (17522/17522)
   remote: Counting objects: 33396, done
   remote: Updating references: 100% (1/1)
   To https://abc.................................................................git
   * [new branch]      master -> master
   ```
8. `git push --mirror test`

   ```
   Counting objects: 35959, done.
   Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
   Compressing objects: 100% (11059/11059), done.
   Writing objects: 100% (35631/35631), 86.91 MiB | 16.52 MiB/s, done.
   Total 35631 (delta 19237), reused 35489 (delta 19127)
   remote: unpack error Invalid tree 300894f515: duplicate entry names
   error: unpack failed: error Invalid tree 300894f515: duplicate entry names
   ```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue with the steps mentioned below.

1. At first I did a --mirror clone.
2. Then executed "git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch **SampleApp**  && git ls-files -s | git update-index --index-info' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all"
3. Then I did a --mirror push.

Here SampleApp is the file that has been corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

Your rewritten history is in `refs/heads/master` (i.e., the `master` branch). But `filter-branch` will have created a backup of the broken history in `refs/original/refs/heads/master`. Your `--mirror` push will send that, causing the other side to complain.

You probably want to `git update-ref -d refs/original/refs/heads/master`.