# remote: error: object: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries

Tags: git

we just try to move our project from old server to gitlab.and I choose to use the method

```
git clone --bare git@xxx.git

git push --mirror gitlab git@xxx.git
```

However,three of my four projects are behave ok,just the left one occour the problem.
   I have tried

```
 git ls-tree
```

and

```
 git replace
```

it won't work. and as I am almost a new to git,I don't know what to do,anyone can help? 3Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [one of the methods of "Tree contains duplicate file entries"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24868719/6309).

Once you know which element is involved, you can use a filter-branch to remove it: see "[duplicate file error while pushing --mirror into Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34309262/6309)"

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter \
  'git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch <yourFile> && \
   git ls-files -s | git update-index --index-info' \
--prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all"
```

(Replace `<yourFile>` by the problematic element)

Comment: Yes try to look at git bundle: it will compress your git repo in one file that you can copy over to your server, and clone --bare from that file, replacing your gitlab bare repo with this one.

Comment: yes,it works,3Q very much   I forgot to replace SampleApp

Comment: @郑迎风 Great! I have edited the answer with the filter-branch command, and make it visible that you have to replace `<yourFile>` (SampleApp for instance) by your actual problematic file.